# uCommerce ITaxService not being called

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I have the followed the steps to create a custom tax service for ucommerce. For arguments sake i want to tax everyting at $500. It would seem to me that the TaxService is not being called.

../UCommerce/Configuration/Components

```
<component id="TaxService"
    service="UCommerce.Catalog.ITaxService, UCommerce"
    type="AMS101.UCommerceCustomisation.CalculateTaxService, AMS101"
    lifestyle="Singleton"/>
```

Implement ITaxService

```
public class CalculateTaxService :ITaxService{
        public Money CalculateTax(Product product, PriceGroup priceGroup, PriceGroupPrice unitPrice) {
            return new Money( 500m, Currency.FirstOrDefault( x => x.ISOCode == "AUD" ) );
        }
    }
```

removed line from basket config

```
<!--<value>${Basket.CalculateOrderLineTax}</value>-->
```

would really appreciate any help.

Comment: see work around http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce/ucommerce-support/24826-VAT-Calculation?p=0#comment126662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try recycling the app pool after making the change to the config file. It might be a simple matter of a stale config being used.

Comment: Thanks soren as you mentioned on another site it is a bug you will have fixed in version 3. http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce/ucommerce-support/32141-No-VAT-on-orders-from-non-EC-countries